# Afinal, se diz "parênteses" ou "parêntesis"?

Tags: ortografia, uso-de-palavras

Vejo muita gente dizendo "parênteses" ou "parêntesis". Há também as respectivas contrações no singular, "parêntese" e "parêntesis".

Observe que, aparentemente, "parêntesis" é igual para singular e plural.

Até onde sei, os dois são corretos, mas há alguma preferência entre os dois? Há diferença, também, no que tange ao grau de formalidade?

Comment: Fazendo jus ao nome “comentário”, eu sempre escrevi “parêntesis”.

Comment: Luiz, *parêntesis* é de facto singular e plural. Isto é típico de palavras que já acabam em -*s* no singular, como *lápis* ou *vírus*. Retirei a tag "sinais-gráficos", porque a pergunta não sobre uso de sinais-gráficos, é simplesmente sobre o nome de um sinal gráfico (do mesmo modo, uma pergunta se é *adjectivo* ou *adjetivo* é de ortografia, não levaria a tag "adjetivo").

Comment: Beleza, @Jacinto, realmente é melhor mesmo, muito obrigado por essa revisão e pela excelente resposta também. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ambas estão corretas: *parêntesis* (singular e plural) e *parêntese* (singular; plural, *parênteses*) vêm ambas em todos os dicionários que consultei: Houaiss (Lisboa, 2002), Academia das Ciências de Lisboa (2001), Sociedade da Língua Portuguesa (Lisboa, 1965) e ainda os online [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/par%C3%AAntesis), [Michaelis](https://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-portugues/busca/portugues-brasileiro/par%C3%AAntesis/), [Priberam](https://dicionario.priberam.org/par%C3%AAntesis) e [Infopédia](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/par%C3%AAntesis).

Todos estes dicionários apresentam as definições apenas em *parêntese*; em *parêntesis* dizem simplesmente que é o mesmo que *parêntese*, sugerindo assim preferência por este. O dicionário da Sociedade da Língua Portuguesa é explícito: diz que *parentese* é a forma preferível.

*Parêntesis* é no entanto a forma mais antiga na língua: aparece, grafado *parenthesis* (aliás, *parẽteſis*), já em 1576 na [*Ortografia da Língua Portuguesa*](http://purl.pt/15) (f. 77) de Duarte Nunes de Leão; *parêntese*, grafado *parenthese*, encontrei apenas a partir do início do século XIX. (*Parenthesis* e *parenthese* são a chamada grafia etimológica, dominante até às reformas ortográficas do princípio do século XX; do mesmo modo, escrevia-se *catholico, christão, theatro, pathetico*, etc.)

Mesmo durante o século XIX, *parenthesis* parece ter sido a forma preferida. As seis edições, de 1789 a 1878, do dicionário de Moraes Silva trazem apenas *parenthesis*; o mesmo se passa com o enormíssimo dicionário de Domingos Vieira de 1874. O dicionário de Cândido de Figueiredo de 1899 é que já traz também *parenthese*.